# ffmpeg: How to create cropped thumbnails?

Tags: images, video, ffmpeg

For creating a video thumbnail with `ffmpeg` I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 thumb.jpg
```

This gives me a thumbnail with the same size of the video (which has an unknown size, e.g. 960x540). But what I need is a square (**cropped**) thumbnail with a given size (e.g. 200x200). The result must not be resized, but cropped from the center, and the aspect ratio should not change.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why use `-itsoffset` instead of `-ss`? I've seen an increased usage of this lately by users making image outputs from videos.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Sorry, mixed up the options. Found this for more info about `-itsoffset` vs. `-ss`: http://superuser.com/questions/538031/what-is-difference-between-ss-and-itsoffset-in-ffmpeg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`crop`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) video filter:

```
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i video.mp4 -vf crop=200:200 -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

- By default the crop will be centered.
- Use `-ss` instead of `-itsoffset` to choose your offset time.
- You can control JPEG output quality with `-qscale:v`. Using a value of 2-5 is usually good; a lower value is a higher quality.
- The `crop` filter can also accept the input and output width and height as values: `iw`, `ih`, `ow`, `oh`. This allows more flexible and creative filtering: `crop=iw-100:ih-50`.

You can test with `ffplay` to get a preview:

```
ffplay video.mp4 -vf crop=200:200
```

Original image (generated with the [`testsrc`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) source filter:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

[image: original image]

Cropped image:
[image: cropped image]

Answer (score 6):

You can scale it first and then crop it for better output ;)

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i "Ali_Video.mp4" -vframes 1 -filter "scale=-1:300,crop=400:300" "output.jpg"
```

[image: input video at 0:49]
[image: output image]

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i "Ali_Video.mp4" -vframes 1 -filter "scale=-1:150,crop=200:150" "output.jpg"
```

[image: another thumbnail]