# Burn in delayed subtitles

Tags: terminal, ffmpeg, subtitles

I would like to burn subtitles into a video file using a console program. Previously I used `ffmpeg` to do that:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=sub.srt -strict -2 out.mp4
```

However, I am having problems when my subtitles are delayed with regard to the movie. I looked into `-ioffset` option and `setpts` filter, but they allow me move the *video*, but I'd like the video timing to stay unchanged and only burn in the subtitles in a delayed manner.

Is there a way to do it in `ffmpeg` (I suppose no, as burning subtitles is a filter and I don't see a way to "change" a behavior of filters, but I haven't looked at all of them)? If not, is there an easy-to-use console program which would delay the subtitles before burning them in?

Answer (score 0):

You can first move the subtitles using ffmpeg as discussed in “[What is difference between -ss and -itsoffset in ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/538038/136765)” and then burn the modified subtitles into your video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:23:45 -i sub.srt sub_moved.srt
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=sub_moved.srt -strict -2 out.mp4
```